# Entity Framework 5.0 Beta - will a DbContext code generation template be provided?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I was working a bit ahead and planning for transition from EF 4.2 CTP to EF 5.0 and when "adding a code generation template" in VS11 + .NET 4.5 the DbContext template is no longer available.  Any heads up on if one will be available and if not why (just curious)?

**Update:**

I see references to a DbContext template in the Enum tutorial, but yet I don't see the template in my VS11 project targeting .NET 4.5 with EF5.0 -pre installed.  I see the other two V5.0 templates (EntityObject and Self-Tracking).  Could it be a conflict with other installations, like in my case, Entity-Framework 4.2 CTP?  I ran into template issues where VS couldn't decide what System.Data.Entity to use and defaulted to 4.2's when trying out EF 5.0.

**Update 2:**

Fresh install of Windows Server 8 Beta, with a fresh install of Visual Studio 11 Beta, still no EF5 DbContext code generation template.  EF 4.2 and template extensions from VS 2010 are not installed, in fact neither is VS 2010.  Just an fyi...

[image: Code Generation Templates Screenshot]

Comment: First you want to uninstall you 4.2 CTP version. It is using binding redirects (and a few other hacks) that will likely cause some unexpected problems to pop up which will be hard to resolve. Note that uninstalling the CTP will break your tools. The Readme from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26660 contains steps showing how to fix this. Once you have VS11, .NET Fx 4.5 Beta (and EF 5.0 beta installed - this is only needed for CodeFirst approach) you should be able to find templates in the "Online Items"

Comment: Here are the steps that worked for me:
1) Click the the edmx file in the solution explorer to open the designer 2) select Add Code Generation Item…. 
3) Select EF 5.x DbContext Generator from Online items and click the Add button

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was afraid of that.  I can't uninstall 4.2 CTP until I've transitioned production code based on it to EF 5.0.  Sounds like I'll be waiting a bit for VS11, EF 5.0, and .NET 5.0 to finalize before proceeding...

Comment: Then I think you are in trouble. EF 4.2 was a CTP and was not meant to be used in production. Betas of VS11 and .NET Framwork 4.5 released a few weeks ago and they both have a "go-live" license (as opposed to EF 4.2 June CTP). I believe that this also means that there will be no major changes between .NET Framework 4.5 Beta and RTM. EF 5.0 beta 2 was released a few days ago and also has a "go-live" license - see the announcement http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/03/22/ef5-beta-2-available-on-nuget.aspx

Comment: Indeed, I understand that and fully understood that prior to taking this direction, but previous versions were so slow it rendered them unusable for a "production" implementation.  I'm fully prepared to make the transition, challenges and all, to continue production use of EF without mixing ORM's.

Comment: Much kudos to the EF team btw, the CTP has been very solid!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't check it myself, but according to this [Entity Framework Releases and Versioning](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=234899)
It will be provided.

Try to install EntityFramework 5 Beta 2 using *install-package EntityFramework -pre* and 
then install [EF 5.x DbContext Generator for C#](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/da740968-02f9-42a9-9ee4-1a9a06d896a2)

Note that starting with the Entity Framework version 4.1 release, the Entity Framework is not part of.NET but is built on .NET. So I think that any related tools will be released separately on nuget or visualstudio gallery.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that it was only provided via an extension...makes sense though...thanks!

Comment: Something else I came across...there's a separate extension for web projects...  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d01a981-91b8-492c-b42c-c771c3f31e03?SRC=VSIDE