# Where does resource Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine1 in EF come from?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm working on an EF6 model-first project that has a customized `.tt` template for generating the `.cs` files. I notice the comments are generated from resource strings such as `Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine1`. Where are these resource files and are they accessible to be altered? I'm just curious.

```
...
fileManager.StartHeader();
#>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
// <#=CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine1")#>
//
// <#=CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine2")#>
// <#=CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine3")#>
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<#=codeStringGenerator.UsingDirectives(inHeader: true)#>
....
```

- As asked previously to no avail on the official forum https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ba8bba03-84bc-4a2d-8ce7-f24bb3161baf/t4-templates-getresourcestring?forum=vsx
- related question [Remove auto generate comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14942636/10245)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are embedded resources into the Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.dll which is located at the visualstudio folder /Common7/IDE/.

With ILSpy or similar you can browse the assembly and find this resource file.

```
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.TemplateResources.resources (Embedded, Public)
```

Comment: How did you know to look in there, out of interest?

Comment: Well, all things start with google, hit Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine1, followed msdn links until found the assembly, then just located it and peeked at it.

Comment: Thanks I might try that out myself as it had looked like a dead end to me :-)