# Extracting classes from ODataV4 Metadata XML in .NET-core

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata, dynamics-crm

I downloaded the file `ODataV4Metadata.xml` from Microsoft Dynamics 365. This file contains many `EntityType` tags in which classes are described. For reference, this is how it (partly) looks:

```
<Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM" Alias="mscrm">
            <EntityType Name="crmbaseentity" Abstract="true" />
            <EntityType Name="accountleads" BaseType="mscrm.crmbaseentity">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="accountleadid" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="accountleadid" Type="Edm.Guid" />
                <Property Name="overriddencreatedon" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" />
                <Property Name="timezoneruleversionnumber" Type="Edm.Int32" />
                <Property Name="importsequencenumber" Type="Edm.Int32" />
...etc
```

This should, for example, generate a class called `Accountleads`, with properties like

```
[DataMember(Name = "overriddencreatedon")]
        public System.DateTimeOffset? Overriddencreatedon
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Overriddencreatedon;
            }
            set
            {
                this._Overriddencreatedon = value;
            }
         }
```

As I'm working in .NET-core it seems rather impossible. I was able to generate a HUGE (100k lines of code) file consisting out of all the `EntityTypes` with lots of comments. However, it seems I am not able to do this in .NET-core, although I am able to use the generated classes.
The second problem is, it generates just one file, with all classes in it (and it doesn't include all the namespaces beforehand using the `using` keyword)

Is there any tool which has some more flexibility, works in .NET-core and generates classes in separate files? Googling it gives many solutions in ASP.NET and .NET v4.

If necessary I will make an Open Source tool to do this, but maybe I haven't looked at enough places.

---

Sources I checked:

- [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126871/entity-framework-generating-classes)
- [Microsoft on OData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The out-of-box tool for creating early-bound proxy classes is [CrmSvcUtil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/create-early-bound-entity-classes-code-generation-tool).

Daryl LaBar has written the [Early Bound Generator](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/DLaB.Xrm.EarlyBoundGenerator/) for [XrmToolbox](https://xrmtoolbox.com), which I believe leverages CrmSvcUtil.

There's a commercial VS add-on for D365 called [XrmToolkit](https://xrmtoolkit.com) that includes the ability to create proxy classes (using a proprietary algorithm, so they are different from the classes that CrmSvcUtil generates). This is the tool I use, and it does create each class as a separate file.

As a side note, Jason Lattimer's [D365 Developer Extensions](https://github.com/jlattimer/D365DeveloperExtensions) has a lot of helpful features, but I don't believe it has built-in proxy class generation.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful and I hope it will help others too